# FOSOAuthServerBundle Configuration

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0

I am really lost trying to configure FOSOAuthServerBundle.

I think I have correctly installed it. Actually, I have created a command for registering new Clients. I have added one, but when I go to `oauth/v2/auth` with the required data, I get errors and errors. Now, I am in one really stopped:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function isAuthorizedClient() on a non-object in /Users/pgbonino/Sites/Symfony/vendor/bundles/FOS/OAuthServerBundle/Controller/AuthorizeController.php on line 62
```

The exact line is the one with the if sentence:

```
    $event = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(
        OAuthEvent::PRE_AUTHORIZATION_PROCESS,
        new OAuthEvent($user, $this->getClient())
    );

    if ($event->isAuthorizedClient()) {
        $scope = $this->container->get('request')->get('scope', null);

        return $this->container
            ->get('fos_oauth_server.server')
            ->finishClientAuthorization(true, $user, null, $scope);
    }
```

Previously I have had other errors, but I think they are solved thanks to forums, documentation and issues. But now I am stopped here.

Any clue on this?

I found also this solved issue in the bundle that seems to be related. But still not able to solve mine: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/pull/46

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

It was a matter of differences between Symfony 2.0 and 2.1 on the treatment they do with dispatchers.

I had downloaded a Symfony2.1 version of FOSAUthServerBundle in  Symfony2.0 environment.

It's well explained in several issues of the bundle itself.